# C++ Prevent Compilation of Full Template Specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization

I have code such as the following, that maps template types to an enumerated value.  However, the value `MyEnum::C` is only defined when the code utilizes the template `something<double>`.  Is there a way to change the template declaration/definition such that the following compiles?

E.g., I thought if I added a default template parameter to the end of the declaration of the `something` template, that would be sufficient to make the full specializations only partial specializations, which would only compile the specializations when used.  However, I couldn't figure out the correct syntax to do so.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum class MyEnum
{
    A,
    B
};

template<typename T>
struct something;

template<>
struct something<int>
{
    static constexpr auto value = MyEnum::A;
};

template<>
struct something<double>
{
    static constexpr auto value = MyEnum::C;
};

int main()
{
    cout << static_cast<int>(something<int>::value) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I thought the following would work, but didn't:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr MyEnum toEnum()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, T>)
        return MyEnum::A;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<double, T>)
        return MyEnum::C;
}
```

Comment: What removes `C` from the enum? Presumably a macro? Can't you disable your specialization with the same macro? Please provide more details.

Comment: The enumeration is generated from an external tool.  There is no associated macro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if you changed the full specialization `something<double>` into a partial specialization depending on some other template parameter `T`, you still cannot use `MyEnum::C` inside that specialization and expect your program to be well-formed, because `MyEnum::C` is a non-dependent construct, and compilers may reject templates containing invalid non-dependent constructs, even if those templates are never instantiated.

For the same reason, sticking `MyEnum::C` into a discarded `if constexpr` branch does not make the program valid.

However, you can do something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename E = MyEnum>
struct something;

template<>
struct something<int>
{
    static constexpr auto value = MyEnum::A;
};

template<typename E>
struct something<double, E>
{
    static constexpr auto value = E::C;
};
```

Now, you're no longer directly mentioning `MyEnum::C`; the dependent construct `E::C` may or may not be valid, depending on whether `E` actually ends up being `MyEnum`.

Whether this strategy is suitable for your particular use case, I have no idea.